# Using jQuery inside an Angular Directive

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using `ng-repeat` to make a long list of `li`s then using an angular directive to check if overflow occurred in the li (because there is a max-height), then I add a 'See More' button in any `li` with overflow

```
App.directive('seeMoreDirective', function() {
     return function(scope, element) {
        var ele = angular.element(element);
        ele.ready(function() {
            if ( ele.prop('offsetHeight') < ele.prop('scrollHeight') ) {
                //overflow detected
                console.log('overflow detected');
                ele.addClass('see-more');
                var seeMore = angular.element("<p class='see-more'><a class='see-more'>See More</a></p>");
                element.after(seeMore);
            }
        });
    };
```

This is an html snippet:

```
<li ng-repeat="topic in topicData | orderBy:'+id'" class="well well-sm">
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="clickable" data-idcode={{topic.id}} ng-click="navigate($event)">
            <p>{{topic.title}}</p>
            <div class="topic-desc" see-more-directive>
                <p>{{topic.opening_comment}}</p>
            </div>
        </div> <!--end clickable div-->
    </div> <!--end col-md-9 div-->
</li> <!--end angular loop-->
```

This works perfectly using jqLite. However when I link jQuery before Angular (I am already using jQuery on my site already, so I figured I might as well use jQuery within Angular) this breaks.

I tried a few other jQuery events, like `load()` but none of them worked.
The only thing that works is when I replace `ele.ready()` with `setTimeout()` with a long delay. I think the problem is the difference between jqLite's `.ready()` and jQuery's `.ready()`, but I can't figure it out. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the template code that uses the `seeMoreDirective` directive? I am a bit confused how this is to be used, but I definitely feel you could do this in a more efficient way.

Comment: Edited to include HTML snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it by passing `$timeout` to the directive and replacing `ele.ready()` with `$timeout()`. Like so:

```
App.directive('seeMoreDirective', function( $timeout ) {
    return function(scope, element) {
        var ele = angular.element(element);
        //ele.ready(function() {
        $timeout( function() {
            if ( ele.prop('offsetHeight') < ele.prop('scrollHeight') ) {
                //overflow detected
                console.log('overflow detected');
                ele.addClass('see-more');
                var seeMore = angular.element("<p class='see-more'><a class='see-more'>See More</a></p>");
                element.after(seeMore);
             }
        });
    };
});
```

I believe the difference is `$timeout` waits until the browser has finished rendering the `ng-repeat` elements, where `ele.ready()` fires after the DOM element is ready. This difference is important in this case because I was using their heights.